# IEnumerable.Intersect with custom comparer, don't understand behaviour

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to create a custom `IEqualityComparer` for an intersect to compare strings using a `Regex`, and I really just don't get what it's doing.

Here's the code, from a LinqPad test.

Comparer:

```
public class RegexEqualityComparer : EqualityComparer<string>
{
    public RegexEqualityComparer(string pattern, RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None)
    {
        _re = new Regex(pattern, options);
    }

    public RegexEqualityComparer(Regex re)
    {
        _re = re;
    }

    public override bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {           
        bool res = false;

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) 
            res = true;
        else if (x != null && y != null)
            res = _re.IsMatch(x) && _re.IsMatch(y);

        String.Format("RES: {0}, {1} = {2}", new object[] { x, y, res }).Dump();

        return res;            
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
    private Regex _re;
}
```

Called with:

```
RegexEqualityComparer comparer = new RegexEqualityComparer(@"^-");

new string[] { "1", "-4" }.Intersect(new string[] { "1", "-" }, comparer).Dump();
```

I am expecting this to give me `{ "1", "-4" }` - both elements from set1 appear in set2 - according to the equality comparer; what it actually gives is:

```
RES: 1, 1 = True
{ "1" }
```

The thing that really confuses me is that according to the LinqPad `Dump()` in the comparer, it never bothers even trying to compare the `-4` with anything - the sole dump is that `RES: 1, 1 = True`

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, but can't see it at all!

Comment: You need a different implementation of `GetHashCode` since different strings will not be compared for equality if their hashcodes are different even if they match by the regex.

Comment: How would `"1"` match the regex pattern `"^-"`?

Comment: I guess your hash code should be something like `return _re.IsMatch(obj) ? 0 : obj.GetHashCode();`

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen A good point; that is actually taken care of by the Object.ReferenceEquals, but it does mean that my intended behaviour is not that clear from the code. I can fix that easily enough now that Jon Hanna has solved the major problem though.

Comment: Just to clarify - you're trying to select at most one string that matches the regex, and all reference-distinct strings that don't match it?

Comment: The logic is: Strings are considered equal if they are the same text or they both match the regex. I have changed the reference comparison to be a normal  == as per Jon Hanna's answer and this is now working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public override int GetHashCode(string obj)
{
    return obj.GetHashCode();
}
```

If `Equals(a, b)` then it is required that `GetHashCode(a) == GetHashCode(b)`. This is not guarnateed by your `EqualityComparer`, and this bug means the matching values are not found by the `Intersect()` call.

A sensible enough implementation to correspond with your `Equals` would be:

```
public override int GetHashCode(string obj)
{
  if (obj == null) return 0;
  if (_re.IsMatch(obj)) return 1;
  return obj.GetHashCode(); // catch the reference-equals part for non-matches.
}
```

The fact that two strings with the same characters would be considered non-equal (i.e. it considers `new string('1', 1)` different to `"1"`) is perhaps deliberate or perhaps a bug. Maybe the `ReferenceEquals()` should be string's `==`?

Comment: Aha! Of course, thankyou that has solved it. I was unaware of that requirement but it's obvious now you mention it!

Comment: Re: last edit, yes, the ReferenceEquals is the next thing to fix for my intended logic.

Comment: It can be useful to short-cut on `ReferenceEquals` but `string`'s `==` does that anyway.